# Can't handle pre_checkout_query telegram bot payment api

Tags: python, bots, payment, telebot

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


@tb.message_handler(commands=['pay'])

def pay(message):
    tb.send_invoice(message.chat.id, title='Test title', description='Test description', invoice_payload='test', provider_token='xxx:TEST:xxx', currency='RUB', prices=[types.LabeledPrice('RUB', PRICE)])

def preCheckoutHandler(preCheckoutQuery:types.PreCheckoutQuery):
    tb.answer_pre_checkout_query(preCheckoutQuery.id, ok=True)
    
def successPayment(message):
    tb.message_handler(content_types=['successful_payment'])
```

After sending a request to "pay" there is a long download, and then shows the window with the error "error occurred while processing the payment. The money from the card has not been written off".

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?